# Induction: $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k = n$

Tags: summation, induction

> Use the proof of induction to show : $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k = n$

I know how to show the base step of this problem, but in showing the inductive step I am having trouble determining how to show they are equal.

Comment: In the inductive step, what are the two values you add at the LHS?

Comment: I added n+1 to the LHS, but I am not sure this is correct, because it is bounded by 2n, as opposed to what I am used to, which is just n.

Comment: I meant that the sum goes from $1$ to $2(n+1)$ instead of $1$ to $2n$, so there are $2$ extra terms on the LHS.

Comment: Please make the body of your question understandable without the title. This way it is easier for people to make sense of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, it is true for $n-1$.
Then  $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k =$$ $$=\left( \sum_{k=1}^{2(n-1)} (-1)^k k\right)+(-1)^{2n-1}\cdot(2n-1)+(-1)^{2n}\cdot(2n)=$$
$$=(n-1)-(2n-1)+2n=n$$
it is also true for $n$.

Answer (score 0):

let the relation holds for n<=m then in particular $\sum_{k=1}^{2m}(-1)^k k = m$
consider $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m+2}(-1)^k k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m}(-1)^k k+ (-1)^{2m+1} (2m+1) + (-1)^{2m+2} (2m+2)=m-(2 m+1)+(2m+2)=m+1 $

Comment: Base Case:  \[\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k = n\]}
\begin{eqnarray*}
(-1)^1 (1) + (-1)^2(2) &=&1 \\
1=1 
\end{eqnarray*}

Inductive Step: For this step we must prove that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k = n \Rightarrow  \sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)} (-1)^k k = n+1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)} (-1)^k k = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k + \sum_{k=1}^{2} (-1)^k k
\end{eqnarray*}
We know that, \[\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k = n\]
and from the base case we conclude, \[\sum_{k=1}^{2} (-1)^k k = 1\]
Therefore in we have $n+1 = n+1$. Is this a method that could be utilized?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ((-1)^{2k-1} (2k-1)+(-1)^{2k}(2k))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-(2k-1)+(2k))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1\\
\end{array}
$

and you can either use induction
to show that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1
= n
$
(which might be a useful exercise)
or you can just say that
it is obvious.